# How to push multiple values in array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have one array`arrayPath` I `push` multiple values in `arrayPath` Which appears in the following code `singleFile.originalFilename` has duplicate(which is shown in console) values, when `singleFile.originalFilename` duplicate values that duplicate value I dont want to push in `arrayPath` how it is possible ?

I tried with below code but i not get right result.

```
var arrayPath = [];
console.log(singleFile.originalFilename); // '3.jpg','5.jpg','3.jpg','3.jpg','8.jpg'
console.log(singleFile.size);  // '1345','5778','1345','1345','7777'

for(i=0; i < files.uploadFiles.length; i++){

  singleFile=files.uploadFiles[i];
  if(arrayPath.indexOf(singleFile.originalFilename) === -1){
    arrayPath.push([singleFile.originalFilename,singleFile.size,'true']);
  }else{
    console.log("some singleFiles are duplicate");
  }
}
console.log(arrayPath);
```

Comment: is singleFile is an object ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS it is array

Comment: @Ankit please check the answer, if i missed the singleFile structure of data, please post the array so i can update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, the files has following structure, you can do:

```
const files = {
  uploadFiles: [{originalFilename: '3.jpg', size: 1345}, {originalFilename: '5.jpg', size: 5778}, {originalFilename: '3.jpg', size: 1345}, {originalFilename: '3.jpg', size: 1345}, {originalFilename: '8.jpg', size: 7777}]
};
const uniqueFilesMap = files.uploadFiles.reduce((map, current) => {
  map.set(current.originalFilename, [current.originalFilename, current.size, 'true']);
  return map;
}, new Map());
const result = [...uniqueFilesMap.values()]; // [["3.jpg",1345,"true"],["5.jpg",5778,"true"],["8.jpg",7777,"true"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Set` to make sure you only have unique values.

```
const x = new Set([1,2,2,4,5,5])
console.log([...x.values()]) // [1,2,4,5]
```

You can read more in the Mozilla Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: If you dont want to use sets you have to write a unique filter or filter just in time during pushing your values.
`function unique(values) {return values.filter(function (value, index, self) { return self.indexOf(value) === index;});}`

Comment: OP is pushing array to the `arrayPath`. Set cannot be used in such cases! `x = new Set([[1], [1], [1]])` will have 3 items in the set.

Comment: @Errorname   const x = new Set([singleFile.originalFilename]) i doing this but console is like this it not remove duplicate  console.log([...x.values()]) // ['8.jpg'],['8.jpg']

Answer (score 1):

i hope you have an array of objects as shown below, where you can write a function which accepts the array and a property.

Based on the property you can filter the array. so by checking you can remove the duplicates and return a new array. we can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

I hope the below code will solve the issue. Since its a function you can use it multiple times and you can filter any property in the array.

```js
let singleFile = [{fileName: "3.jpg", size: 1234}, {fileName: "4.jpg", size: 1236},
{fileName: "5.jpg", size: 1237},
{fileName: "3.jpg", size: 1234},
{fileName: "3.jpg", size: 1234}]

// method accepts array and property
// you can check with property on the array and remove  duplicates from array and return a new array
const removeDuplicates = (array, property) => {
 let uniq = {}
 return array.filter(obj => !uniq[obj[property]] && (uniq[obj[property]] = true))
}


console.log(removeDuplicates(singleFile, "fileName"))
```

Comment: TypeError: array.filter is not a function this type error i get

Comment: so can you post the array that you are passing to the removeDuplicates function ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have code like this.

```
var arrayPath = [];
console.log(singleFile.originalFilename); // '3.jpg','5.jpg','3.jpg','3.jpg','8.jpg'
console.log(singleFile.size);  // '1345','5778','1345','1345','7777'

for(i=0; i < files.uploadFiles.length; i++){

  singleFile=files.uploadFiles[i];
  if(!this.isArrayDataUnique(singleFile.originalFilename)){
    let obj = {
      filename: singleFile.originalFilename,
      size: singleFile.size,
      status: 'true'
    };
    arrayPath.push(obj);
  }else{
    console.log("some singleFiles are duplicate");
  }
}
console.log(arrayPath);

function isArrayDataUnique(originalFileName){

 let filters = arrayPath.filter(item => item.filename === originalFileName);
 return filters.length;
}
```